# XNA Perlin Noise Planet

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, terrain, perlin-noise

I want to make an procedural planet with XNA.
I'm able to create an heightmap with Perlin Noise and load it in run-time, but how do I create additional seamless chunks and create a spherical planet?

Thanks in advance, Giulio.

Comment: Hows it going so far on this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out how I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697079/generating-terrain-in-c-sharp-using-perlin-noise/9796235#9796235)

Thats assuming you are making a platformer, or is it topdown?

However because you need chunks, using how I did it may not work so good, So you could use [this](https://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/perlin-noise-in-c/) implementation of perlin noise, and use it as seen in the link below.
You may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697079/generating-terrain-in-c-sharp-using-perlin-noise/9796235#9796235) for chunks

Comment: I'm trying and trying, but I don't know how to make seamless perlin noise and deform it to make a planet...

Comment: Well if you use a Perlin Noise algorithm, Each "chunk" will leave off were the last one was. However, Doing it backwards, like having one end connect to the last... I see alot of 3D planets on youtube, If any have source code, changing the noise to 1D should work. Now that I think about this seems pretty hard.